# Only one slider works at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

If you click the WORK link at the bottom you will see a working slider using the carouFredSel plugin. Upon clicking the IMG link the second slider appears and does not follow the parameters of only showing one at a time. This occurs with whatever slider I set to show first and they are using pretty identical scripts. I've gone about the toggle multiple ways and this always occurs, I'm guessing it's something to do with switching the display variable but I don't know what to do about it

```
$("#img-carousel").carouFredSel({
    width: "100%",
    height: 450,
    direction: "right",
    circular: true,
    infinite: true,
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        height: 400,
        width: 400
    },
    scroll: {
        duration: 1000,
        pauseOnHover: true
    },
    auto: {
        timeoutDuration: 9999,
        delay: 5000
    },
    prev: {
        button: "#img-left",
        key: "left"
    },
    next: {
        button: "#img-right",
        key: "right"
    },
    pagination: {
        container: "#img-pagination",
        keys: true
    },
    swipe: true,
    mousewheel: false
});

$("#web-carousel").carouFredSel({
    width: "100%",
    height: 450,
    direction: "right",
    circular: true,
    infinite: true,
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        height: 400,
        width: 720
    },
    scroll: {
        duration: 1000,
        pauseOnHover: true
    },
    auto: {
        timeoutDuration: 9999,
        delay: 5000
    },
    prev: {
        button: "#web-left",
        key: "left"
    },
    next: {
        button: "#web-right",
        key: "right"
    },
    pagination: {
        container: "#web-pagination",
        keys: true
    },
    swipe: true,
    mousewheel: false });
```

Anyone have any insight on the problem? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats the issue?? Works fine here.  Tested with Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 and Firefox v21.0 even IExplorer v9.0.8112 works...

Comment: @KyleK I get the problem here in Chrome 28. When you click on IMG, the carousel shows three items at a time instead of just 1.

Comment: oooooohhh...I see what you mean....you just want one image.......to be honest, I actually liked the fact that there were three for IMG, it was a little different...and the fact that they're thinner, made it seem natural....but now that I select IMG first, and then the WEB, that doesn't look so good...as 3....so I get what you mean now.......Ive actually had this same problem when working with carouFredSel before...my workaround at the time was fixed width....not 100%...it didn't seem to like 'responsive' layout, so I ended up redesigning the site as a fixed site, just to use my slider...lol

Comment: Hahaha so is there no better way around it?